# How to place html elements at the mouse position when it moves, without lag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drawing

I'm currently working on a web-based drawing app that does not use a canvas. The reason I am avoiding using a canvas, is because I am going to add CSS Keyframes to the html elements as they are placed. It also allows me to keep track of each individual div, as I can give them incrementing ids.

The way I am currently placing the divs, is with Jquerys's .on("mousemove")...
The problem I am running into is that if you move your mouse too fast, it creates gaps in the line.

The question I have is whether there is a way to generate a line between the gaps.

I made a JSFiddle with a snippet of the code. https://jsfiddle.net/ThemeJared/d16yjg9L/

Thanks,
   Jared.

```
var mousePosX, mousePosY, style, circle;

var windowHeight = $(window).height(), // Height of entire window
    windowWidth = $(window).width(); // Width of entire window

$(document).on("mousemove", function (event) {
    mousePosX = event.pageX; // px amount of mouse pos
    mousePosY = event.pageY; // px amount of mouse pos
    style = "top:" + (mousePosY - ($('#circle').height() / 2)) + "px; left: " + (mousePosX - ($('#circle').width() / 2)) + "px;";
    $("<div id='circle' style='" + style + "'></div>").appendTo('#drawpad');
});
```

Comment: "*I can give them incrementing ids*" - you should probably do that in your demo, then; because they currently all have the *same* `id`.

Comment: You can't speed up the mousemove event unfortunately it's generated by the browser - check this out. http://blog.toggl.com/2013/02/increasing-perceived-performance-with-_throttle/

Comment: AND this - personally I dont get any lag using canvas http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/#demo-complete

Answer (score 0):

Since you know every mouse event, you can save the context of the previous event and calculate the distance between this one and the previous. From that you can add any number of circles along the line between the previous and the current position. You dont need more events to generate a line.